# How do I extend the desktop environment to the secondary display?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, desktop-environments, displayport

### TLDR:

- The **primary monitor didn't work** (connected over displayport)
- I found **I could manually turn it on via `nvidia-settings`**
- It now works, **but doesn't show the desktop environment**
- I can move the mouse and windows over (see image below)

[image: Photo of how the secondary screen glitches out]
*The throwback to Windows 95 is real*

---

*I've dreamt about migrating my main workstation to Linux for a while. Now that I'm finally doing it, it's not going great... Any help is greatly appreciated!*

### Background

1. I bought a new drive for the Linux install (so I still have a working Windows install on the other. It doesn't have any problems with the primary display)
2. Hardware: Nvidia RTX 2070 with two displays:

   - DP 1.4 (8k cable) -> 4k 120hz primary display
   - HDMI 2.1 (8k cable) -> 1440p 60hz secondary display
3. The HDMI display works fine

   - the 4k display also works over HDMI, but it only has HDMI 2.0 input - meaning it's capped at 60hz. Which I can't live with. (And even if I could, the GPU only has one HDMI output, so it's not an alternative).

### What I did

1. Installed the latest version of Ubuntu (23.10) (I tried PopOS first - had the exact same issue)

   - Only the secondary monitor (1440p) works
2. Checked display settings

   - Only the secondary display shows up
3. Opened nvidia-settings

   - Both displays are listed
   - The primary display's resolution is set to `off`
   - I set the resolution to 4k
   - The display turns on, but is all black
   - I can move the mouse over
   - I can also move windows over (leaves a trail of flashing after-images that doesn't go away. When I let go after dragging the window over, it jumps back to the main display, and snaps to the side - read: window snapping)
4. Still nothing more detected in the settings app

### What I've tried

1. I've tried all alternative nvidia driver versions available under the `Additional drivers` tab

   - No luck
   - nouveau works, but 4k @ 120hz glitches out and only displays the bottom half of the primary display
2. arandr

   - Configuring the primary display with arandr gives exactly the same result as nvidia-settings
3. Secure boot has been disabled the whole time (I've heard it can impact proprietary drivers)

### Debugging information

*On fresh install - no edits (Ie. forcing screen on with nvidia-settings)*

```sh
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1440 x 2560, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1440x2560+0+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   3840x2160     60.00 + 119.91    59.94    50.00    30.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   2560x1440    120.00  
   1920x2160    143.84  
   1920x1080    119.88    60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
USB-C-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

```sh
$ sudo dmesg | grep nvidia
[    6.759834] nvidia-gpu 0000:2b:00.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    7.154534] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 236
[    7.155955] nvidia 0000:2b:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[    7.320920] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  535.113.01  Tue Sep 12 19:45:42 UTC 2023
[    7.332442] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002b00] Loading driver
[    8.402918] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:2b:00.0 on minor 0
[    8.562022] nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
[    8.586552] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 511.
[ 3464.800039] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002b00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 3464.800102] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002b00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 3464.800141] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002b00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 3464.800173] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002b00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 3464.874065] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002b00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 3464.874126] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002b00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 3464.874159] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002b00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 3464.874190] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002b00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 3464.950322] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002b00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 3464.950383] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002b00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 3464.950417] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002b00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[ 3464.950448] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002b00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
```

```sh
$ nvidia-smi
Sat Mar 16 15:41:21 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.113.01             Driver Version: 535.113.01   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070        Off | 00000000:2B:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   45C    P8              22W / 175W |    418MiB /  8192MiB |     18%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      4391      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          138MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4632      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         63MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5567      G   /usr/bin/gnome-control-center                11MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5713      G   ...irefox/3216/usr/lib/firefox/firefox      141MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7164      G   /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor                   11MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

### After forcing the second monitor on with `nvidia-settings`:

```sh
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 510.47.03

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung S27H85x"
    HorizSync       27.0 - 89.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-4"
    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=left}, DP-2: 3840x2160_120 +1440+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```